# Pass data through browser to JSP: Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I'm passing data from my browser to `HomeController.java` by just changing the URL,
[image: URL]

My `HomeController.java` as follows,

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping("home")
        public String home(HttpServletRequest req) {
            HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            String name=req.getParameter("name");
            //Fetch data comming from client
            System.out.println("hi "+name);
            session.setAttribute(name, name);
            return "home";
        }
     }
```

I'm passing session attribute using `session` object but how should I fetch that in my JSP file(`home.jsp`).

my `home.jsp` looks like :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome ${name}
</body>
</html>
```

I want to write java code in `home.jsp` file and use the session object instead of the `expression language` format. Can anyone tell how to use that session object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can call your variable from the session object like so :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `name` is the name of the object stored in your session.

**PS : use a Logger instead of System.out**

Comment: Now its getting name as null. the name is not parsing correctly

Comment: try to use a fixed session object name; so instead of having `session.setAttribute(name, name);` use something like `session.setAttribute("myObject", name);` and then replace it in jsp : `<%=session.getAttribute("myObject")%>`